# how to provide username and password for chef windows_zipfile recipe

Tags: authentication, chef-infra, chef-windows

I'm trying to use `windows_zipfile` resource from the Chef Supermarket [windows cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/windows), but the source URL that I am using needs to have user privilege's to fetch any artifacts.

How can we add username and password to `windows_zipfile` resource?

```rb
windows_zipfile 'c:\test_app' do
  source 'https://artifactory/repoName/ApplicationName/zipfile.zip'
  action :unzip
end
```

Comment: Is the `source` a URL? The one mentioned in your question doesn't look like something that requires privileges.

Comment: @seshadri_c updated source

Answer (score 2):

The `windows_zipfile` custom resource *does not* have any properties to accept credentials for the URL. *More importantly* the cookbook as a whole is being deprecated in favour of the native `archive_file` resource.

> **Note**: This resource has been deprecated as Chef Infra Client 15.0 shipped with a new archive_file resource, which natively handles multiple archive formats. Please update any cookbooks using this resource to instead use the `archive_file` resource.

I would recommend downloading the file using [remote_file resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/remote_file/) by providing the credentials. Then you can use `archive_file` (if Chef version > 15), or `windows_zipfile` to extract the file from local path.

```rb
remote_file 'C:\test_app.zip' do
  source 'https://artifactory/repoName/ApplicationName/zipfile.zip'
  remote_user 'user'
  remote_password 'secret'
end

# showing example for 'archive_file'
archive_file 'C:\test_app' do
  source 'C:\test_app.zip'
  action :extract
end
```